# MySQL SUM cells with same ID and insert it in table

Tags: mysql

please help my with that:
I have this table:

```
id      key         value
1       term1       35
1       term2       
1       term3       40

2       term1       12
2       term2       
2       term3       11

3       term1       51
3       term2       
3       term3       23
```

Each `id` has in the `key` column `term2` which is sum of `term1` and `term3`.
And that sum should be inserted in `value` column. 
Like this:

```
id      key         value
1       term1       35
1       term2       75
1       term3       40

2       term1       12
2       term2       23
2       term3       11

3       term1       51
3       term2       74
3       term3       23
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the table, use `join`:

```
update table t join
       (select id, sum(value) as sumvalue
        from table t
        where key in ('term1', 'term3')
        group by id
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.value = tt.sumvalue
    where t.key = 'term1';
```

Note that `key` is a keyword in MySQL (and SQL in general).  I'm keeping the name, because that is how the question is phrased.

Comment: Wouldn't the last "where" statement have "term2"?  The current statement would overwrite the OPs term1 value thus corrupting their data.

Comment: Thank you! But if I want to multiply them. `term2=term1 * term3` ?

Comment: Got it: I use `EXP(SUM(LOG(value)))`